# Make sure that a string is exactly a 5 digit number

Tags: vba

I want to return true if some strings = 'XXXXX'

Where every X is a number 0 through 9

I know there must be a dozen ways to do this but I would like to know the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the simplest way, you can go with this:

```
Function MyFunction(myString As String) As Boolean
    MyFunction = ((Len(myString) = 5) And (IsNumeric(myString)))
End Function
```

If you want the more efficient way, you'd have to run some tests for the different methods people suggested.

Edit: The previous solution doesn't work well (see the first 2 comments) but I'm letting it there since it's what has been accepted. Here is what I would do :

```
Function MyFunction(myString As String) As Boolean
    Dim myDouble As Double
    Dim myLong As Long
    myDouble = Val(myString)
    myLong = Int(myDouble / 10000)
    MyFunction = ((Len(myString) = 5) And (myLong > 0) And (myLong < 10))
End Function
```

There is no error "protection" in that function, so if you try to check a too large number like 22222222222222, it will not work.

Comment: A four digit negative number would pass both of those tests - e.g. -3621 has five characters and is numeric. Decimal points (36.21) or thousand separators (3,621) would also cause problems

Comment: True enough! Also, if the string is "00005", it would pass the validation I think.

Answer (score 4):

```
yourString Like "#####"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar question previously asked: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992922/how-do-i-express-the-term-if-x-is-integer-in-vba-language)

Basically want to check

```
(Len(s) = 5) And IsNumeric(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions to solve this problem. If you include Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 in your VBA project, you can use `RegExp` and `MatchCollection` variables as in the function below. (This is a modification of the response to [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37624&page=1) at ozgrid.com.)

```
Public Function FiveDigitString(strData As String) As Boolean

On Error GoTo HandleError

Dim RE As New RegExp
Dim REMatches As MatchCollection

    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    If REMatches.Count = 1 Then
        FiveDigitString = True
    Else
        FiveDigitString = False
    End If

    Exit Function
HandleError:
    Debug.Print "Error in FiveDigitString: " & Err.Description
    FiveDigitString = False
End Function
```